# How to operate on the "page" object of PhantomJS from CasperJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, headless-browser, slimerjs

I have a piece of PhantomJS code and I want to refactor it and move to CasperJS. However, in my original PhantomJS code, I have some lines of code directly operate on the `page` object and I'm not sure how to translate them to CasperJS. Below is part of my original code.

```
var cookies = "C_B_A=2; tips=1;";
var page = require("webpage").create();
page.settings.userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.104 Safari/537.36";
cookies.split(";").forEach(function(pair){
    pair = pair.split("=");
    phantom.addCookie({
        "name": pair[0],
        "value": pair[1],
        "domain": ".mydomain.com"
    });
});
```

I searched CasperJS documentation and there seems no cookie related methods. Here my question is, is there any way for me to reference the underling PhantomJS `page` object and set its attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can access it with `casper.page` or `this.page` inside of casper closures, but most of the time there is no need, because CasperJS provides better alternatives for PhantomJS functions.

The `phantom` object is also just there in CasperJS (regardless whether you use SlimerJS or PhantomJS as the underlying engine).

Comment: Thank you! Let me give it a try. Do you mean `phantom` object is only available when SlimerJS is used?

Comment: No, it is available when you use --engine=phantomjs and --engine=slimerjs. So in both.